# Get output from remote command invocation

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have this simple code to execute a .bat file remotely through PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  servername -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process "\\servername\D$\LocalApp\application\script.bat"
}
```

The script works fine. The only issue is that I need to be able to see the output in the CMD window while it executes.

Comment: What kind of output do you generate with your script.bat? Just "ECHOs" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use the call operator (`&`) instead of `Start-Process`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  servername -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
  & '\\servername\D$\LocalApp\application\script.bat'
}
```

or run `Start-Process` with the parameters `-NoNewWindow` and `-Wait`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  servername -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process '\\servername\D$\LocalApp\application\script.bat' -NoNewWindow -Wait
}
```